# Using both Azure AD and Azure AD B2C to authenticate with SSO

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My Azure web application will have both internal and external users. The requirements regarding authentication are:

- Internal users authenticate with their domain accounts (with SSO)
- External users authenticate through Azure AD B2C (we need to create accounts for them)

How can I set up such scenario?

Regards

George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your internal users are using Azure AD - simple - you add your corporate AAD as Identity provider to your B2C.
There are various ways to do this. So start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

If your internal users do not have Microsoft 365 (Azure AD), and you only have on-premises AD DS infrastructure - ... move to Cloud, things will be so much easier. If not, you need at least ADFS, then you can hook up [ADFS as Identity Provider in your B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

There is no way to make Windows Integrated Authentication and Claims Based authentication at the same time for the app.

Comment: Same scenario for me - I have B2C for external users (some local users, some from a connected identity provider), and now the requirement is to allow existing internal users (who are in a separate Azure AD) to also log in to our app (React SPA) - but the owners of the internal users won't connect that AD to B2C as an identity provider - @astaykov is there any way to make this work with that identity provider connection?
The only option I can think of is to do something horrible on the front end using MSAL to allow multiple sign in options, and configure 2 authentication schemes on the API.